# If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ is divisible by $16$, then show that$ a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is divisible by $64$. Where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ is divisible by $16$, then show that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ is divisible by $64$; where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

I began by proving that if $(a^3+b^3+c^3) -(a^2+b^2+c^2)$ is divisible $16$, then $a^3+b^3+c^3$ will be divisible by $64$. That is equal to $a^3-a^2+b^3-b^2+c^3-c^2$ $= a(a^2-a)+b(b^2-b)+c(c^2-c)$.

But this doesn't give a clear path for the question.

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any way offhand to continue with what you started to finish the proof.

Instead, note that perfect squares have remainders of only $0$, $1$, $4$ or $9$ when divided by $16$. As such, if $a^2$ had a remainder of $1$, the other $2$ would need to have remainders which sum to $15$. This is not possible as the only options are $0$ plus $1$, $4$ or $9$, $1 + 1 = 2$, $1 + 4 = 5$, $1 + 9 = 10$, $4 + 4 = 8$, $4 + 9 = 13$ and $9 + 9 = 18 \equiv 2 \pmod{16}$. Similarly, if $a^2$ had a remainder or $4$ or $9$, the other $2$ also can't add up to give a multiple of $16$.

This means that all of $a^2$, $b^2$ and $c^2$ must have a remainder of $0$ when divided by $16$, i.e., each of $a$, $b$ and $c$ are multiples of $4$. Thus, each of $a^3$, $b^3$ and $c^3$ must be a multiple of $4^3$, i.e., $64$, so their sum is as well.

**Update:** As [Will Jagy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10400/will-jagy)'s [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3676977/if-a2-b2-c2-is-divisible-by-16-then-show-that-a3-b3-c3-is-d#comment7555914_3676996) indicates, since perfect squares have remainders of only $0$ or $1$ when divided by $4$, this means $a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ can be a perfect square only if $a$, $b$ and $c$ are all even. If you factor out $4$, then for $\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{c}{2}\right)^2$ to be a multiple of $4$ again requires each half value to be even. This means each of $a$, $b$ and $c$ has to be a multiple of $4$ which, as before, results in $a^3 + b^3 + c^3$ being a multiple of $64$.

Comment: you can also say that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ cannot be divisible by $4$ unless all the variables are even. Then do it again. So each is divisible by $4.$   If we had $w^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2,$ we need it divisible by $8$ for all the variables to be forced even

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the feedback. That is a useful method to solve this problem, as well as other related problems.

Comment: Did you mean $a^\color{red}2, b^\color{red}2, $ and $c^\color{red}2$ must have a remainder of $0$ when divided by $16$?

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, of course, thanks for pointing out the typos when I've now fixed.

Comment: I put a bunch of pdfs at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/  Initially, it was just unpublished stuff by Kap. One simple item is that a positive ternary quadratic form must be anisotropic for at least one prime (that divides the discriminant); this comes from a global product for the Hilbert Norm Residue symbol.  That's the behavior here with prime $2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner  you are also thanked for pointing out the missing exponents. Thanking is associative.

Comment: @WillJagy I'm having one of those days. I didn't notice that it was J.W. Tanner who pointed out the missing exponents.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I'm sorry for not noticing it was you who pointed out the missing exponents.

Comment: John, in case of interest, the properties of the 102 simplest forms $a x^2 + b y^2 + c z^2$  are summarized in this one page: http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~kap/Dickson_Diagonal_1939.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks for the link to that page. It looks interesting, including things like the very first entry of $ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2$, where $a = b = c = 1$, with the result of $A = 4^k(8n+7)$.

Comment: Glad you like it. Note that each form has such a $p^{2k}$ obstruction for an odd number of primes; examples with three are $1,21,21$   and $3,3,7$  and $3,7,7.$

Comment: @JohnOmielan thank you abundantly for extensively solving the question. I think this method is great!

Comment: @WillJagy:  in your comment above, did you mean thanking is *transitive*?  ($A$ thanks $B$ and $B$ thanks $C\implies A$ thanks $C$)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner good point. I believe I had thanking as a mapping of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

We may write:

$$16\big|a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ac)$$

⇒ $$4\big| a+b+c$$

Also:

$$8\big| ab+bc+ac$$

Since the phrases are symmetric if one is a multiple of 4 others will also be, Hence a, b and c are multiple of 4 so the sum of their cubes are  a multiple $4^3=64$.

Comment: thanks for providing the alternative method.